# How to filter TreeMap<MyKey, Map<Key2,List<Kids>>> ,

Tags: java, java-stream, grouping, treemap, collectors

FundingRank and SourceBucket are enums but essentially int

```
enum FundingRank {
    LESS_THAN_0(0),
    LESS_THAN_1(1),
    LESS_THAN_100(100);

    private final int rank;
    FundingRank(int i) {
        this.rank = i;
    }
}

enum ScoreBucket {
    MORE_THAN_1000(1000),
    MORE_THAN_500(1000),
    MORE_THAN_100(100),
    MORE_THAN_10(10);

    private final int bucket;
    ScoreBucket(int i) {
        this.bucket = i;
    }
}
```

I have a `TreeMap<FundingRank, TreeMap<scoreBucket, List<Kids>> >` holding data like

```
fundingRank  scoreBucket List<Kids>
0              1000       List(with 1 elements) 
                500       List(with 2 elements)
                100       List(with 4 elements)
                 10       List(with 3 elements)
1             1000        List(with 4 elements)
                500       List(with 7 elements)
                100       List(with 4 elements)
                 10       List(with 3 elements)
```

Now I , want to find element minimum `fundingRank` and maximum `scoreBucket` with minimum 5 kids, if not then minimum `fundingRank` and maximum `scoreBucket`

```
 myMap.entrySet().stream()
     .filter(e -> e.getvalue().entryset().stream()
         .filter(e2 ->e2.getvalue().size()).findfirst();


Output sorted map like this:

1 500  List(with 7 elements)
0 100  List(with 4 elements)
1 1000 List(with 4 elements)
1 100  List(with 4 elements)
0 10   List(with 3 elements)
...
```

So, I am trying to sort the TreeMap<Int, TreeMap<Int, List>>, the sort order is defined as  MinFunding rank and max ScoreBucket (with threshold 5, if bucket has 5 kids, meaning if there is any other smaller bucket with more kids, the higher score bucket wins, or if there is a bigger FundingRank with higher bucket size and more kids, still the lower fundingBucket row wins if it meets 5 kids threshold), then pick up the 1st row
hope it is clear now

Comment: Can you give some examples about what you want to achieve here?

Comment: Don't understand what you want as result ? And minimum 5 kids meaning sum up all kids of  a fundingRank ?

Comment: `List<Kids>` is the value type in the *nested* `TreeMap<Key2, List<Kids>>`, I think OP means `List<Kids>.size() >= 5`. `MyKey` seems to be `fundingRank`, an `Integer`, and `Key2` seems to be `scoreBucket`, another `Integer`. Then again I could be totally off, OP should [edit] their question and add more details and clarity.

Comment: Your example sort order doesn't match with your text

Comment: @Eklavya, If you elaborate I can try to fix it , I am trying to sort the TreeMap<Int, TreeMap<Int, List<Kid>>>, the sort order is defined as  Min funding rank and max ScoreBucket (with priority if bucket has 5 kids, meaning if there is any other smaller bucket with more kids, the higher score bucket wins, or if there is a bigger FundingRank with higher bucket size and more kids, sill the lower fundingBucket row wins if it meets 5 kids threshold), then pick up the 1st row

Comment: For sorting comparision order is important, like compare check A field if equal then compare B field if equal then compare C field this way.

Comment: But for your case, there is no particular order.

Comment: this is the order  --  order is defined as MinFunding rank and max ScoreBucket (with threshold 5, if bucket has 5 kids, meaning if there is any other smaller bucket with more kids, the higher score bucket wins, or if there is a bigger FundingRank with higher bucket size and more kids, still the lower fundingBucket row wins if it meets 5 kids threshold)

Comment: Despite all the comments, I still don't fully understand your requirements. Do you want to filter? Or do you want to sort? Or do you want to find the `[fundingRank, scoreBucket, list_Kids]` triplet with the min funding and max score, but only if the list of kids has more than 5 elements? Sorry, but it's not clear

Comment: You are saying the first sort by min funding  then how  `1` comes first I don't understand. You care this lines _For sorting comparision order is important, like compare A field if equal then compare B field if equal then compare C field this way._

Comment: @Eklavya,  no I am not saying first sort by fundingBucket, I am saying sort by the `combination rule` I gave above. pls, review the data,  see that  FundingBucket #0 does not have any row(entry) with > = 5 kids , that is why we went for fundingBuket #1,  so in my view if we sort it , the correct row will automatically bubble up  ( I guess like heap)

Comment: It's not possible because you must follow a comparison order for sorting by multiple fields.

Comment: @fps Objective: want to find the [fundingRank, scoreBucket, list_Kids] triplet with the min funding and max score, but only if the list of kids has more than 5 elements , but if none of the ScoringBucket has >=5 kids than just return minFundingBucket and max ScoreBucket and corresponding list of kids

Comment: OK, understood that part. And what happens when there are 2 lists with more than 5 kids? i.e. both lists have 8 kids, one with score = 1 and another one with score = 2, both with same rank = 0 ?

Comment: Also, does the size of the list of kids *always* have precedence over rank and score?

Comment: @fps: Q1: what happens when there are 2 lists with more than 5 kids ->  scoreBucket#2 ranks higher if they are in same FundingBucket

//** Q2:  does the size of the list of kids always have precedence over rank and score -  only if  size of list<kids> >=5 otherwise min Bucket, max Score ranks higher. for. e.g.
min Fundingbucket 0 , scoreBucket#1000 has list_size(3) and minFundingBucket#0 , scorebucket#500 has list_Size(4)  --> then scoreBucket#1000 still wins, b/c other buckets not crossing threshold of list_size(5)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find the `[fundingRank, scoreBucket, list_Kids]` triplet with min `FundingRank` and max `ScoreBucket`, but only considering triplets with more than 5 kids, you could stream the entries of your outer and inner maps and use a custom `Comparator` to find it:

```
Optional<Map.Entry<FundingRank, Map.Entry<ScoreBucket, Integer>>> triplet = 
    outerMap.entrySet().stream()
        .flatMap(outerEntry -> outerEntry.getValue().entrySet().stream()
            .map(innerEntry -> Map.entry(
                 outerEntry.getKey(), 
                 Map.entry(innerEntry.getKey(), innerEntry.getValue().size()))))
        .min(Comparator.comparingInt(t -> t.getValue().getValue() >= 5 ? 0 : 1)
            .thenComparing(t -> t.getKey())
            .thenComparing(t -> t.getValue().getKey(), Comparator.reverseOrder())
            .thenComparing(t -> t.getValue().getValue(), Comparator.reverseOrder()));

triplet.ifPresent(it -> /* do something with the triplet */);
```

This creates triplets as `Map.Entry<FundingRank, Map.Entry<ScoreBucket, Integer>>` and finds the min triplet, according to the given `Comparator`, which (I hope) fulfils your requirements.

We're using a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) in [`Stream.min`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#min-java.util.Comparator-) that first sorts by either `0` or `1`, which is a flag that specifies whether there are more than 5 kids or not. This flag is `0` if there are more than 5 kids, so that triplets with more than 5 kids appear first. Then, the comparator sorts by `FundingRank` ascending, then by `ScoreBucket` descending and, finally, if there is a tie, it's broken by the actual number of kids descending (just in case).

Here I've used the Java 9+'s [`Map.entry(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entry-K-V-) method to create entries. If you're on Java 8, you should create entries with [`new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html#SimpleEntry-K-V-).

Comment: holly molly! happy debugging, too :D

Comment: Hi @Eugene! I'm not sure if the `Comparator` chain will compile without adding witness types...